# How to solve broken pipe error in SourceTree when pushing 10 files at a time?

Tags: git, ssh, putty, sourcetree

I am getting this error when I am pushing 10 files from Windows 8 system, from SourceTree.

> FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   fatal: sha1 file '' write error: Broken pipe
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Completed with errors, see above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This this also happen from the command line?

Comment: The number of files you are pushing shouldn't affect anything. Are they large files?

Comment: its not large , its just around 1 mb